# Analog of subset for lists

Tags: r

I'd like to subset a list of sublists, based on the contents of one of the sublist elements, in a manner similar to the way `subset` works on data frames:

```
sublist1 <- list(data=rnorm(10), name="name1", keepMe=2)
sublist2 <- list(data=rnorm(10), name="name2", keepMe=2)
sublist3 <- list(data=rnorm(10), name="name3", keepMe=3)
myList <- list(s1=sublist1, s2=sublist2, s3=sublist3)
```

I'd like to do something like `keepers <- subset[myList, keepMe==2]` which would return a list of length 2.

The following is *almost* what I want:

```
require(plyr)
selector <- function(x) {
  if (x$keepMe==2) {return(x)} 
  else {return(NULL)}
}
keepers <- llply(myList, selector)
```

except that in that case the undesirable list elements don't get thrown out, they just get replaced with `NULL`.

Note that in all cases the sublists will have the same components, only the values of the components change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the two lists with TRUE in the `keepMe` position:

```
myList[ unlist( sapply(myList, "[", "keepMe") ) ]
```

@ttmaccer solution omitting the `i=`

```
myList[ sapply(myList, "[[", "keepMe")  ]
```

(Which succeeds because `sapply` will try to deliver a vector or matrix if it can, but "[" returns a list, while "[[" returns an atomic logical.)

Comment: So much nicer than my solution. +1. I still haven't quite figured out how/when to use `[` and `[[` and so on with the apply functions. Any tips?

Comment: I edited the problem to reflect my actual problem more closely: the keepMe elements will contain a number, and I want to select certain numbers / ranges. I can't quite figure out how to apply @DWin's solution (which was great for the question I asked) to the problem I actually face. Sorry 'bout that change, DWin.

Comment: Even shorter version to be added.

Answer (score 2):

This *works* but I don't know if there is a more direct way:

```
keepers = myList[-(which(sapply(1:length(myList), 
                                function(x) myList[[x]]$keepMe == FALSE)))]
```

Here's the `str()` of the resulting list:

```
str(keepers)
# List of 2
# $ s1:List of 3
#  ..$ data  : num [1:10] -0.82 0.487 0.738 0.576 -0.305 ...
#  ..$ name  : chr "name1"
#  ..$ keepMe: logi TRUE
# $ s2:List of 3
#  ..$ data  : num [1:10] -0.0449 -0.0162 0.9438 0.8212 0.5939 ...
#  ..$ name  : chr "name2"
#  ..$ keepMe: logi TRUE
```

Comment: Seems like there ought to be a more direct way, doesn't it? Something involving sapply(myList, "[[", ...) - but I can't quite get there.